# Postgresql: Adding Carriage Return in Column headers

Tags: postgresql

My query is as follows:

```
SELECT col1 AS "a Long Striiiiiiiiiiiiiiing1" 
FROM table1
```

(I'm asked to use that long string for column header)
is there and way to inject a carriage return in column header so that it be displayed as:

```
a long striii
iiiiiiiiiing
```

My Postgresql version is 8.4. And I have tried Followings, and none of them works:

```
  SELECT col1 AS U&"a Long Striiii\n iiiiiiiiiiing1" 
        FROM table1 
    SELECT col1 AS E"a Long Striiii\r\n iiiiiiiiiiing1" 
        FROM table1 
SELECT col1 AS E"a Long Striiii\000 iiiiiiiiiiing1" 
        FROM table1 
SELECT col1 AS U&"a Long Striiii\000 iiiiiiiiiiing1" 
        FROM table1
```

Comment: where are you trying to display these headings? It is really up to the product the displays the results on how it handles wrapping of headings.

Comment: Unrelated, but: why are you using such an outdated and [unmaintained](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) version?

Comment: Good question! But I don't dare to ask my supervisor, cause I'm new to the company

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use a literal line feed without any escaping:

```
test=> SELECT 42 "A really
test"> strange header";

    A really   +
 strange header 
----------------
             42
(1 row)
```

Comment: I tried it but it's truncated instead of displaying in two lines

Comment: My example above shows that it isn't. Perhaps your client can't cope with newlines in column headers, which would not surprise me.